# R: jsonlite/geojsonio: Why are these geoJSON polygons being read in different formats? And how to deal with them for shp exportation?

Tags: shapefile, r, geojson, convert

EDIT: Turns out `fromJSON()` has a variable called `simplifyVector` that by default goes `TRUE`. By setting it to `FALSE` I was able to turn the string into Json, from Json into geoJson and from geoJson into spatialpolygonsdataframe. Still don't know why it happens, though.

I have these two polygons in geoJSON format I got from an API and I want to export them to shp. When I read these two polygons using `fromJSON()` I get two different formats. Apparently, the reason would be because the second polygon includes a third coordinate in some of its vertex. Why is it happening?

It's worth noting that I've been successfully able to export the polygons to shp in the second format of the reproducible example below, but I haven't had the same success with the first format. How could I "standardize" them so I could  read multiple polygons in these two possible formats, and export them to shp files?

Here's a reproducible example:

`Polygon1 <- '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-70.3248,-27.3708],[-70.3247,-27.3713],[-70.3246,-27.3719],[-70.3245,-27.3723],[-70.3239,-27.3743],[-70.3198,-27.374],[-70.3194,-27.3724],[-70.3193,-27.3719],[-70.3196,-27.3704],[-70.3201,-27.3696],[-70.3204,-27.3695],[-70.3222,-27.3693],[-70.3248,-27.3708]]]}'`

`Polygon2 <- '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-70.597,-33.4169,0.0],[-70.5952,-33.4144],[-70.5947,-33.4139],[-70.5926,-33.4133],[-70.5921,-33.4133],[-70.5907,-33.4138],[-70.59,-33.4142],[-70.5885,-33.4152],[-70.5894,-33.4163],[-70.5916,-33.4195],[-70.5918,-33.4197],[-70.5929,-33.4191],[-70.5943,-33.4184],[-70.5955,-33.4177],[-70.597,-33.4169,0.0]]]}'`


`Geojson1 <- fromJSON(Polygon1)
print(Geojson1)
Geojson2 <- fromJSON(Polygon2)
print(Geojson2)`

And the output of the above code:

`print(Geojson1)
$type
[1] "Polygon"
$coordinates 
, , 1
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
[1,] -70.3248 -70.3247 -70.3246 -70.3245 -70.3239 -70.3198 -70.3194 -70.3193 -70.3196 -70.3201
        [,11]    [,12]    [,13]
[1,] -70.3204 -70.3222 -70.3248
, , 2
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]    [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
[1,] -27.3708 -27.3713 -27.3719 -27.3723 -27.3743 -27.374 -27.3724 -27.3719 -27.3704 -27.3696
        [,11]    [,12]    [,13]
[1,] -27.3695 -27.3693 -27.3708`

`print(Geojson2)
$type
[1] "Polygon"
$coordinates
$coordinates[[1]]
$coordinates[[1]][[1]]
[1] -70.5970 -33.4169   0.0000
$coordinates[[1]][[2]]
[1] -70.5952 -33.4144
$coordinates[[1]][[3]]
[1] -70.5947 -33.4139
$coordinates[[1]][[4]]
[1] -70.5926 -33.4133
$coordinates[[1]][[5]]
[1] -70.5921 -33.4133
$coordinates[[1]][[6]]
[1] -70.5907 -33.4138
$coordinates[[1]][[7]]
[1] -70.5900 -33.4142
$coordinates[[1]][[8]]
[1] -70.5885 -33.4152
$coordinates[[1]][[9]]
[1] -70.5894 -33.4163
$coordinates[[1]][[10]]
[1] -70.5916 -33.4195
$coordinates[[1]][[11]]
[1] -70.5918 -33.4197
$coordinates[[1]][[12]]
[1] -70.5929 -33.4191
$coordinates[[1]][[13]]
[1] -70.5943 -33.4184
$coordinates[[1]][[14]]
[1] -70.5955 -33.4177
$coordinates[[1]][[15]]
[1] -70.5970 -33.4169   0.0000`

Comment: Maybe try rjson, I find the combinations of simplify in jsonlite make it unuseable because there are incompatible outputs depending on when matching-dimension assumptions are met. You can have no simplify but then every coordinate single value is in its own list, which is hard to interpret. I haven't explored this enough to understand it fully, but rjson might work for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If the task is to create a shapefile , you could write to file and use `sf::st_read("file.geojson");` then use `st_write` to write out (rows that all have the same geometry type) to one shapefile.

I believe the direct answer to the question is that in the first, the simplify logic detects that a 2-coord*13 can be an array, and perhaps the outer "[" is detected as a degenerate dimension (see that it's 3D 1x2x13, or maybe 2x1x13, and not 2x13). In the second, the first and last also have a 3-coord, so that array simplify logic does not kick in.

You'll want to find out why those start and end coords are XYZ but the rest are XY. (And if that's "normal" then I really want to find out why too).